# Grails, horizontal scroll of page, how can I do that

Tags: grails, scroll, gsp

I have a view where a lot of data is displayed in a table. I have to have a big screen to see it all but can not count on that users always have that size as I have. 
But unfortunately my grails project doesn't support horizontal scroll so if your screen isn't wide enough, you aren't able to see the rightmost part.

What can I do to get the view scroll horizontal?
I use version 3.2.4 of grails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following style to your gsp, overflow is discussed [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp):

```
<style type="text/css">
    table {
        display: block;
        overflow-x: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks! that was an easy one, easy to fix but not so easy to find